# Ajax success append HTML with fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending html to a `<ul>` on an ajax success function.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="revisionList">
  <!-- ajax.js will insert ordered list here based on number of revisions -->
</ul>
```

**Ajax Success**

```
success: function(json)
        {
            /*
            If successful build the list of revision links
            Links include link that will load images in next tab
            */

            //loop through revisions and display
            for(i = 0, j = json.revision_count.length; i < j; i++) {
                //count for revision number
                var k = i + 1;
                //revision number, does not match k
                var revisionID = json.revision_count[i].layout;
                $('#revisionList').append(
                    "<li><a onclick=\"initEditRevision(" + galleryID + ',' + revisionID + ")\" href=\"#editRev\" data-toggle=\"tab\">Revision " + k + "</a></li>"
                );
            }

        }
```

How do I go about fading in the whole `<ul>` after the list is built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
success: function(json) {
    var $list = $('#revisionList');
        $list.hide();  // Hide Here
    for (i = 0, j = json.revision_count.length; i < j; i++) {
        var k = i + 1;
        var revisionID = json.revision_count[i].layout;
        $list
            .append("<li><a onclick=\"initEditRevision(" + galleryID + ',' +  
                     revisionID + ")\" href=\"#editRev\"
                    data-toggle=\"tab\">Revision " + k + "</a></li>");
    }
    $list.fadeIn('slow'); // Fade In here
}​
```

Comment: Why are you hiding in the for loop! It is doing it over and over

Comment: @epascarello .. thanks for pointing it out.. Over looked it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (...

}
$("#revisionList").hide().fadeIn();
```

Or perhaps you can hide it before the `for` loop; whatever works best.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide it using CSS `display` property firstly or using style attribute if you don't want to use CSS.

```
#revisionList{display: none;}
```

OR

```
<ul id="revisionList" style="display: none;">
```

then fade in after that all `li`s appnded completely.

```
$("#revisionList").fadeIn(500);
```